# Differential equation in exact differentials.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

here is the problem: $$(3t^2x-1+x^2)dt+(t^3+2tx)dx=0$$

I got stuck at the point where the derivatice of $C(x)$ needs to be found.

$$P = 3t^2x-1+x^2, Q=t^3+2tx$$

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}=3t^2+2x; \frac{\partial Q}{\partial t}=3t^2+2x \Rightarrow \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t}$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=P(t,x) \Rightarrow u=\int P(t,x)dt + C(x)$$

$$u=\int (3t^2x-1+x^2)dt + C(x) = t^3x-t + x^2t + C(x)$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=Q(t,x), \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}= t^3+2tx+C'(x)$$

$$C'(x)= 0 $$

$$C(x) = x$$

$$u(t,x)=t^3x-t+x^2t+x$$

I don't know how to express $C(x)$ from here because it seems that it will contain both $x$ and $t$. Can someone help? Also Why is C dependant on $x$ instead of $t$?

Comment: You have an error, you lost the $x^2t$ term which you need to be there in order to determine $C(x)$. You also differentiated $u$ with respect to $x$ incorrectly after that error.

Comment: @Ian I corrected my error, but the result is still incorrect.

Comment: $C'=0$ so $C$ is constant, and now the solution is any curve of the form $u=c$.

Comment: @Ian No, the solution is different from what you're saying.

Comment: No, it is not, unless they go one step further and solve for one of them in terms of the other (which can only be done locally anyway, so usually we don't do it). You should get $t^3 x + x^2 t - t = c$. Check that the LHS has the desired partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

Define $$\frac{\partial P(t,x)}{\partial x}=3t^2+2x=\frac{\partial Q(t,x)}{\partial t}$$ 
defining $f(t,x)$ such that
$$\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial t}=P(t,x)$$ and $$\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial x}=Q(t,x)$$ and the solution will given by $$f(t,x)=c_1$$
$$f(t,x)=\int x^2+3xt^2-1dt=-t+t^3x+tx^2+g(x)$$
then differentiating
$$\frac {\partial f(t,x)}{\partial x}=t^3+2tx+\frac{d g(x)}{dx}$$
so $$\frac{d g(x)}{dx}=0$$
we get
$$f(t,x)=-t+x^2t+xt^3$$
Now substitute $$f(t,x)=c_1$$ and solving for $x(t)$

we get $$x(t)=\frac{-t^3-\sqrt{t}\sqrt{t^5+4t+4c_1}}{2t}$$
$$x(t)=\frac{-t^3+\sqrt{t}\sqrt{t^5+4t+4c_1}}{2t}$$